# Problemas con setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buenas tardes: Estoy utilizando varios setTimeout junto con "animated" para suavizar las transiciones entre los paneles que muestra el sistema.
Ya que tengo que utilizar esos métodos varias veces, creé varias funciones las cuales llamo dependiendo del módulo que esté activo y la acción a realizar.

Por ejemplo, cuando hago click en el botón NUEVO, llamo a la función correspondiente y le envío 4 parámetros: 'newrunner' es el panel que se necesita, 'load' es la acción cargar el formulario con el evento load de JQuery, 'a' es el delay que utilizará la biblioteca animated para hacer el efecto y 2000 es el tiempo que utilizará setTimeout.

```
runners_panels_actions('newrunner','load','a',2000);
```

La funcion runners_panels_actions hace lo siguiente:

```
var currentDelay = 'delay-'+delay;
var time = Number(time);

setTimeout(function() {
   $('.newrunner-panel').load('../../modules/runners/newrunnerForm.php', function() {
      $('.viewrunner-panel').removeClass('active');
      $('.newrunner-panel').addClass('active').addClass('animated fadeIn '+currentDelay);
      $('.newrunner-panel').css('display', '').css('display', 'block');
   });
}, time);
```

Luego cuando hago click en GUARDAR, descargo(unload) el formulario:

```
runners_panels_actions('newrunner','unload','a',1000);

$('.newrunner-panel').removeClass('active').removeClass('animated').removeClass('fadeIn').removeClass(currentDelay);
$('.newrunner-panel').addClass('animated').addClass('fadeOut').addClass('delay-a');
setTimeout(function() {
   $('.newrunner-panel').css('display', '').css('display', 'none');
   $('.newrunner-panel').html('');
   $('.newrunner-panel').removeClass('animated').removeClass('fadeOut').removeClass('delay-a');
}, time);
```

Luego envío los datos al servidor por medio de Ajax de JQuery y, dependiendo de la respuesta (success o error), cargo el mensaje correspondiente para luego "descargar"(unload) el mensaje y llamar a la función que carga y muestra la tabla con los registros actualizados.

```
runners_panels_actions('messagerunner','loadsuccess','a',1200);

setTimeout(function() {
   $('.runner-message-panel').load('../../modules/main/success_message.php', function () {
      $('.runner-message-panel .panel-heading h1').removeClass('register-error').addClass('register-success');
      $('.runner-message-panel .panel-heading h1').text('¡Registro Procesado Satisfactoriamente!');
      $('.runner-message-panel .panel-row1 h1').text('');
      $('.runner-message-panel .panel-body').css('display', '').css('display', 'none');
      $('.runner-message-panel .panel-row1').css('display', '').css('display', 'none');
      $('.runner-message-panel').css('display', '').css('display', 'block');
   });
}, time);

runners_panels_actions('messagerunner','unloadmsg','a',8000);

$('.runner-message-panel').addClass('animated fadeOut delay-a');
setTimeout(function() {
   $('.runner-message-panel').css('display', '').css('display', 'none');
   $('.runner-message-panel').removeClass('animated').removeClass('fadeOut').removeClass('delay-a');
   $('.runner-message-panel').html('');
}, time);

runners_panels_actions('listrunners','load','a',9000);

setTimeout(function() {
   $('.listrunner-panel').load('../../modules/runners/runnersTable.php', function() {
      $(this).removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn');
      $(this).css('display', '').css('display', 'block');
      $('#btn-new-runner').attr('disabled', false);
      $('#btn-search-runner').attr('disabled', false);
   });
}, time);
```

Bueno, los problemas que se me presentan son los siguientes:
1.- A pesar de que cada setTimeout tiene un tiempo específico para realizarse, cuando hago click en GUARDAR, por ejemplo, cada llamada se realiza una detrás de otra de forma seguida, incluso cuando apenas ha ocultado el formulario. Esto me ha dado como error que en ocasiones se "salta" el mostrar el mensaje de success o error y se va directamente a mostrar la tabla con los registros actualizados.

2.- También en ocasiones cuando llamo, por ejemplo, a la función

```
runners_panels_actions('messagerunner','loadsuccess','a',1200);
```

No aplica algunas de las funciones contenidas dentro del setTimeout, sobretodo las que colocan el display block, disculpen tanto código pero quiero que tengan todo lo necesario para que puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: A pesar de todo el código, está incompleto. Considera publicar un [mcve].

Comment: La verdad que no sé qué otro código necesitas

Comment: ¿Leíste la página que enlacé?